# What are some potential pitfalls to using URL rewriting with SSL?

Tags: http, ssl

Using URL rewriting for session management for plain HTTP communication is a recipe for disaster, however, does some of that risk go away if you're using SSL (https)?

Comment: This thread posted by @Jim G. is worth reading for anyone interested: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/758002.html

Basically: yes, some of the risk goes away. Because HTTP is an application layer protocol while SSL/TLS applies to TCP (a transport layer protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SSL mitigates the threat of a man-in-the middle attack.

The only shortcoming is that, with a long-running session, a hacker could potentially capture the session id in a server log and use it for malicious purposes.